# Remove spaces from first column of colon-delimited file

Tags: bash, sed, text-editors, awk, string-manipulation

I have a very large colon-delimited file with two columns:

```
dhsj fdksjdk:dndkdlkfkd
shfdosod dkjsosjd:dkj dosjeod
dhswisoaidodisbw: dhsoi wjdos
fjfdododjfideefkjso sn:fhfdkd dkdjdf
```

If the first column contains a space, I need to remove it (i.e. collapse text together):

```
dhsjfdksjdk:dndkdlkfkd
shfdosoddkjsosjd:dkj dosjeod
dhswisoaidodisbw: dhsoi wjdos
fjfdododjfideefkjsosn:fhfdkd dkdjdf
```

**In other words, everything to the left of the colon needs to be stripped of spaces, and everything to the right of the colon needs to remain untouched.**

I know how to use `cut -d ":" f1` to pull the first column and `tr -d '[[:blank:]]'` to filter out space or tab characters, but then I would have to place that column back into the file and this seems like a roundabout way of doing things.

What's the most efficient way to do what I want here?

Comment: Can you post sample input file and the desired output?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like that:

```
$ awk -F: '{gsub(/ /, "", $1); print $1 FS $2}' FILE
dhsjfdksjdk:dndkdlkfkd
shfdosoddkjsosjd:dkj dosjeod
dhswisoaidodisbw: dhsoi wjdos
fjfdododjfideefkjsosn:fhfdkd dkdjdf
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'm always amazed at how powerful `awk` is, I should learn it one day.

Comment: Quick clarification, does this also strip leading spaces?

Comment: @Prometheus: yes